# Listener oracle in pacemaker cluster

Tags: oracle, linux, listener

I need some help. I have created a cluster with 2 nodes. I created all resources, but listener has errors and the pacemaker cluster status shows Oracle Listener has stopped.

In the web interface I have the following error messages:

> Failed to start listener_or on Mon Oct 25 16:30:52 2021 on node lha1: Listener pdb1 appears to have started, but is not running properly:

and

> Unable to get metadata for resource agent 'ocf:heartbeat:oralsnr' (timeout)

In pacemaker cluster status I have the following error message:

> listener_or_start_0 on lha1 'error' (1): call=35, status='complete', exitreason='Listener pdb1 appears to have started, but is not running properly: ', last-rc-change='2021-10-25 16:30:52 +03:00', queued=0ms, exec=393ms

However, I can connect to the base.

Do you have any ideas how I could solve this issue?

Comment: which account runs the oracle listener and the database?

Comment: In pcs "run listener" set - user: oracle.

Comment: Work done. I create tnsnames.ora and reload services. It.s all work. Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the agent couldn't see the Oracle listener.

The solution was to:

- Create tnsnames.ora
- Write configurtion
- Reload services

After this the pcs didn't have any errors.